# Class library project build error, broken references

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget

The class library project in Visual Studio is throwing an error when I try building it. The error says:

> "Your project is not referencing the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore."

This project is under source control and builds perfectly on other machines with the same Visual Studio version installed. The projects's target network is 4.5.2 as specified in project file.

[image]

project.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Test Class Library",
  "authors": [ "author" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { }
  }
}
```

I noticed when I build the project, the file `project.lock.json` gets generated in the project folder, and in it .NETPlatform verision is set to be `".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0"`. Not sure if this is what causing this problem. It if does, why would `project.lock.json` set the version to 5.0?

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? So far, I am unable to build this project on my machine.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This looks like a good question.

Comment: :) That's what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by not using NuGet for this project anymore.

1. Removed all NuGet packages from the project.

   - Right-click the project in Visual Studio
   - Manage NuGet Packages...
   - Uninstall packages one by one until there are none
2. Deleted **project.json** file in the root directory of the project.
3. Restarted the Visual Studio. This step might not be necessary, but sometimes when you remove **project.json** file, you get the NuGet related error when building the project. If this happens, restart the Visual Studio.

Comment: how did you exclude it!

Answer (score 4):

Hit this issue with VS2017, what it happened is we converted a dotnet core project back to use .Net frameworks. The old `project.assets.json` was left in `obj` folder. And it caused this error. When the file or the `obj` folder is removed, it builds fine.

Comment: How this doesn't have more upvotes is beyond me. Worked perfectly, thanks.